# How to extend default user model in django2.12

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a project and i am not using the default django user model instead i am using my own custom user model. but i am experiencing a problem. For my user model i have also made my own authb.py file which i have provided below and if i am using the default django authentication then it is authenticating only my superuser and not the user that i am entering through the sign up form and i am totally stuck.

first here is my authb.py
    from .models import User

```
class AuthB:

def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
    try:
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return user
    except:
        return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        return User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    except:
        return None
```

but right now i am not using this authb instead i am using default authentication.
here is my models.py for user model

```
class User(models.Model):
is_authenticated = True
username = models.CharField(max_length= 25)
email = models.CharField(max_length= 150)
password = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
profilepic = models.CharField(max_length= 255, default= "")

def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

here is my views.py file

```
def signup(request):
# context = {}
# return render(request, 'sign-up.html', context)


if request.method == 'POST':
    # print(request.POST)
    # Get form values
    username = request.POST['username']
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']

    # Check if passwords match
        # Check Username 
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
        return redirect('signup')

    else:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            return redirect('signup')

        else:
            u = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email)
            u.save()
            return redirect('login')
else: 
    return render(request, 'sign-up.html')

def login(request):
# context = {}
# return render(request, 'index.html', context)


if request.method =='POST':
    # print(request.POST)
    email = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']

    u= auth.authenticate(email=email, password=password)
    return redirect('index')
else: 
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

The main problem is that simple user is not able to login in my website only admin are able to login and django i not authenticating my simple user.

Comment: I don't understand what `AuthB` is for, or why you have posted it if you are not using it.

Comment: But in any case, your User model needs to inherit from AbstractBaseUser. And have you set the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting?

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) carefully to learn how to implement your own custom user. Why are you trying to implement your own authentication backend? You haven't explained what you need that's different from Django's built-in backend.

Comment: sir authb is the file from where i am authenticating the user and to access that file i have change some of my settings. i.e. i have added this command in my setting AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS= ('instashot.authb.AuthB',)

Comment: sir now i have added AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'instashot.User' but in the django official site it is saying that you have to add this command before any migrations

Comment: and can you tell me how can i inherit Abstractbaseuser in my code.